# Can we use Unmanaged Instance group for external HTTPS load balancer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I am planning to create an External HTTPS load balancer on GCP but in my use case there are no identically configured VMs and i need to make sure it should be a highly available (HA) setup.

So as no identical VMs i am planning to go with Unmanaged instance group(for backend-service configuration in LB) but in gcp documentation it is mentioned that unmanaged instance group is not suitable for HA.

can you help me out which approach we need to choose for this use case?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why are your VMs not identical?

If you put them in the same Unmanaged Instance Group, and then to an backend service the same request may end up in any of the VMs, so they need to serve the same content, for the same request.

- Can you give an example of your use case?

As in case you need more VMs to respond to the requests depending on the load for example, it is required to have a single image that can be provisioned on multiple VMs.

Another solution would be to have different backend services for each unique VM type, so that way every unique VM type would be in its own Managed Instance group.

I don't think there is another way, beside Managed Instance Group to achieve HA with VMs instances in GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Unmanaged means not managed! And it means a lot.

- no health check: If your VM is down, slow, unstable (...) nothing is performed by the instance group
- no scalability: in case of increase or decrease of the usage, the instance group won't create or delete instance.
- no instance rollout: you have a new version of your VM (with patches, new app versions,...), the instance group won't ensure a roll out without downtime.

Because, it's not managed, you have to ensure all these things by yourselves. Not impossible, but a lot to do. Or switch to a managed instance group, even if your group is only 1 VM!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give some suggestions on how to make your infra setup as reliable :

1. Get global https LB
2. Even though you have different VM config still get the managed instance group as backend
3. Get ssl cert for your domain if used and make it secure too

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using different backend services for each unique VM type, so that way every unique VM type would be in its own Managed Instance group and set up the https load balancer and it worked!